# How do I get the values out of the following - Items map[string][][]*int64 `locationName:"values" type:"map"` using Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I need to get the values out of the following data that is from the Go SDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/apigateway/#Usage). I am using golang 1.17.

Below is the data returned by my lambda function.

```
Decoded Data:  { map[]}
All the usage:  map[4wxq8mcov8:[[0xc000353848 0xc000353870]]]
{
EndDate: "2021-08-31",
Items: {
4wxq8mcov8: [[12,975]]
},
StartDate: "2021-08-31",
UsagePlanId: "w4wuvt"
}
```

I only want the data from the Items: {api_key: [[this number, and this number]]}, and I only want the two numbers that are in the array.

Example return data and I want the 12 and the 975 -
`Items: { 4wxq8mcov8: [[12,975]] }`

How do I go about getting the data and then dividing the two numbers to get a percentage? Once I get the percentage, I will use that number to compare against the usage plan to see if the threshold is met. If the threshold is <= the divided number, I will send a message via SNS to slack or an email.

Right now my focus is to get the numbers out of the items map. Thank you in advance.

```
  package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "time"
    
        "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/apigateway"
        "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
    
        logging "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    )
    
    type UsageData struct {
        APIKey string               `mapstructure:"api_key"`
        Value  map[string][][]int64 `mapstructure:"values"`
    }
    
    func parseUsage(usage *apigateway.Usage) {
    
        u := usage.Items
        var data UsageData
        err := mapstructure.Decode(u, &data)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    
        fmt.Println("Decoded Data: ", data)
    
        fmt.Println("All the usage: ", u)
        fmt.Println("Items value one %v and value two %v: ", u.Items.ValueOne, u.Items.ValueTwo)
    }
    
    func getUsagePlanInfo(client *apigateway.APIGateway) *apigateway.Usage {
    
        currentDate := time.Now()
        startDate := currentDate.Format("2006-01-02")
        endDate := currentDate.Format("2006-01-02")
    
        input := &apigateway.GetUsageInput{
            UsagePlanId: aws.String(os.Getenv("USAGE_PLAN_ID")),
            KeyId:       aws.String(os.Getenv("API_KEY")),
            StartDate:   aws.String(startDate),
            EndDate:     aws.String(endDate),
        }
    
        results, _ := client.GetUsage(input)
    
        logging.WithFields(logging.Fields{
            "UsagePlanId EV":  os.Getenv("USAGE_PLAN_ID"),
            "KeyId EV":        os.Getenv("API_KEY"),
            "StartDate EV":    startDate,
            "EndDate EV":      endDate,
            "Usage Plan Info": results,
        }).Info("Values")
    
        //fmt.Println("Usage Plan Data: ", results.Items)
        parseUsage(results)
    
        return results
    
    }
    
    func handler() {
        theSession := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    
        srv := apigateway.New(theSession)
    
        u := getUsagePlanInfo(srv)
    
        fmt.Println(u)
    
    }
    func main() {
    
        lambda.Start(handler)
    }
```

Comment: "I only want the data from the Items" - what does that even mean? You need to clarify what the output is (use `fmt.Printf("%+v"` instead) and clarify what you are trying to extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the two numbers you would have to fetch them from the map. If you always know the key and you know that there will only be one element in the array you can do it like this

```golang
u := getUsagePlanInfo(srv)

items := u.Items

quota := *items["4wxq8mcov8"][0][0]
remaining := *items["4wxq8mcov8"][0][1]
```

to be safer you should do

```golang
if item, ok := items["4wxq8mcov8"]; ok && len(item) > 0 && len(item[0]) > 1 {
  quota := *item[0][0]
  remaining := *item[0][1]

  fmt.Printf("%d, %d\n", quota, remaining)
}
```

If you have more than one key or you don't know the key you have to iterate the map and fetch values for each key